# Convert date from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm and replace it to yyyymm in SQL (db2)

Tags: sql, db2

The following code was used when the user passed a parameter for example: 2022-03-25 and converted it to 20220325

```
CASE WHEN LENGTH('$P!{DATE}') = 10
     THEN REPLACE(SUBSTR('$P!{DATE}', 1, 10), '-', '')
     ELSE '$P!{DATE}' END
```

However now I need instead of converting to 20220325 to just 202203, any help?

Comment: If you care about the format, you don't actually have a date value at all and your schema is broken. Real date values are stored in **binary** and are not human-readable at all. Anything you see otherwise is just a convenience provided by the query tool.

Comment: Yes, but what I am looking for is to do exactly the same as in the previous example but with the condition that it is only year and month

Comment: Since you don't actually have a date but just a string that happens to look like one, this is simple string manipulation. `LEFT(..., 6)`.

Comment: Can you add it as an answer (full code if possible)? If it works to mark it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: That logic is assuming some things about the format. But change the 10 to 7 (in the SUBSTR call and I bet it works.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: It didn't work for me, I'm using db2, I don't know if that affects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to have been any purpose for the `substr()` after it was determined the length is 10. But as that appears to work, just eliminate the last three characters. (Last two would also ultimately still work.)

```
CASE WHEN LENGTH('$P!{DATE}') = 10
     THEN REPLACE(SUBSTR('$P!{DATE}', 1, 7), '-', '')
     ELSE '$P!{DATE}' END
```

Comment: It did not work for me, the report returned empty

Comment: An empty result doesn't imply this part was incorrect. We'd need to see the rest of the query.

Comment: With the code that I provide at the beginning it works, when I pass as parameter 202203 it also works, the problem is that it initially receives 2022-03-01 and it must be converted to 202203.

Comment: Is there other logic elsewhere based on parameter length? Again without the rest of the query it's impossible to know. Extracting 7 characters and replacing hyphens with blanks should clearly work just as well as is did with 10.

Comment: I understand you, but it wouldn't make sense for it to work with the previous code and not this one, I'm using db2, I don't know to what extent that affects.

Comment: Yes, that seems right which is why I keep suggesting you look at other parts of the report logic especially where the length of the param comes up.